# How to mock api in react jest enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using json-server to create API services.
When using `fetchMock.mock("endpoint")`, fetch mock actually giving call to back end API and returns data from json server instead of mock data. Please help me.

```
it("Should create a GET_LOGIN_INFORMATION action", () => {
    const loginInfoMockData = [
      { role: "admin", username: "akshay.jadhav.aj1@gmail.com" },
      { role: "staff", username: "jadhavakshayjj8@gmail.com" }
    ];

    fetchMock.mock("*", {
      body: loginInfoMockData,
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" }
    });

    const expectedAction = {
      type: ActionConstant.GET_LOGIN_INFORMATION,
      loginInfo: loginInfoMockData
    };

    const store = mockStore({ loginInfo: loginInfoMockData });
    return store.dispatch(LoginAction.getLoginInformation()).then(() => {
      expect(store.getActions()[0]).toEqual(expectedAction);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: better provide your code. you may misuse `fetchMock` or make mistype in URL to be mocked, or it's a known issue for particular `fetchMock` version etc.

Comment: @ skyboyer please check now

Comment: does your component use `fetch()` to send request? if you use some library to handle that is may utilize XmlHttpRequest under the hood

Comment: @skyboyer using axios to communicate with backend